# NGINX limit_req_zone - limit_req are blocking immediately

Tags: nginx

want to protect wp-login from brute force attacks.
I want to limit to 15 attempts/requests of the wp-login.php file per minute.

I added this rule to nginx.conf

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=wordpress:10m rate=15r/m;
    limit_req_status 429;
```

And to a global.d/secure.conf file I added the following:

```
location = /wp-login.php {
    limit_req zone=wordpress;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

The problem is that the first time I enter a [www.example.com/wp-login](http://www.example.com/wp-login) I get a 502 bad gateway error. If I refresh the page, I get the 429 error.

I expected the wp-login to work. Only after 15 attempts it should fail.

Anybody knows what I am doing wrong? For the time being you can test the behavior in [this](https://www.masazrelaksacyjnywarszawa.pl/) website. Just append /wp-login.php or /wp-admin

EDIT: I had wrong the path of the sock. I changed it to `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;` and now there is a different behavior:
it shows a blank page for /wp-login.php.
Also the problem is that it shows it immediately at the first attempt. Not after 15 tries within 1 minute, and the code is 200.

Comment: Check the nginx error log.

Comment: Thank you I edited the original post. I found the issue. Now the problem is different. It gives a blank page. No errors in error.log this time.